# Android how to make list item height increase to accommodate the content

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-xml

I am using a simple `ListView` in which every item contain only a text field and nothing else. 
Here is my xml code for the list item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textColor="#878787"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

and here is my layout for the fragment using the list view.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e5e5e5">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now, while creating an object of the adapter in my fragment like this

```
Level weather_data[] = new Level[] {
    new Level(R.drawable.s1, 
              "Some text which will be present in the list item",      
              R.drawable.play_button)
        };
```

If I have a very long sentence in the second parameter ie the text, some part of it does not get displayed and the sentence is displayed incomplete in the list item.

I have tried using `android:minHeight` to change the height of the list item but it didn't work. What could be the solution to this?
Thanks

Comment: I guess it is because you have given the TextView height as 50dp.Make it WrapContent to take the size of the text.

Comment: @user2012 no, it still doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to set the container to `wrap_content` and it will be resized when need. Your shown layout is not complete and I simply suspect that you may have something hardfixed here:

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight
```

Also there's no real point in you layout to wrap `TextView` in `LinearLayout` and then all in `FrameLayout`. You can get the same effect with padding and bg moved to `FrameLayout`

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what exactly i should set as "wrap_content" ?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `wrap_content` instead of `"?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` within `android:layout_height`.

Something like this:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: any other way to rectify this issue ?